# Regex to replace the last n delimiters in record

Tags: regex, replace, record

I have a csv file with records like this:

```
^Tablete Internet^|GoClever|^TAB I71^|^Tableta GoClever TAB I71, InfoTMIC iMAPx220 1GHz MKV, MOV, VOB, DAT, WMV, AVI, 3GP, MP4, RM, RMVB, FLV, MKV, MOV, VOB, DAT, WMV, MP3!WAV!OGG!FLAC!APE!AAC, Conectori: 1x mini jack 3.5 mm, 2 porturi USB 2.0, 4000 mAh lithium-ion polymer 3.7V^!92.00!USD!w!24!0!Link!!^5 ron^!!|
Group|Prod|Den|Description!12!EUR!^wait time^!160!Modified!Link!^Spec Obs^!^tv none^!more!info|
```

I need to replace the last 10 of the "!" from the end of the row with "|" so finaly it will look like:

```
^Tablete Internet^|GoClever|^TAB I71^|^Tableta GoClever TAB I71, InfoTMIC iMAPx220 1GHz MKV, MOV, VOB, DAT, WMV, AVI, 3GP, MP4, RM, RMVB, FLV, MKV, MOV, VOB, DAT, WMV, MP3!WAV!OGG!FLAC!APE!AAC, Conectori: 1x mini jack 3.5 mm, 2 porturi USB 2.0, 4000 mAh lithium-ion polymer 3.7V^|92.00|USD|w|24|0|Link||^5 ron^|||
Group|Prod|Den|Description|12|EUR|^wait time^|160|Modified|Link|^Spec Obs^|^tv none^|other|info|
```

I've tried with:

```
sed 's/!\([^\^!]*\)!\([^!]*\)$/|\1|\2/'
```

but this replaces only the last 2 occurences of "!". If I try

```
sed 's/!\([^\^!]*\)!\([^!]*\)!\([^!]*\)$/|\1|\2\3/'
```

it does not match anything... So how can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need to use regex? It is probably easier to write a script that parses the input file and generates an output file.

Comment: I am writing a script... it is converting from excel xls to csv and I need to parse the bad resulting csv so I can selectively import some data in a mysql database. And I need to do all this with bash tools and some perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know is not the most elegant solution but I've managed to do it with:

```
perl -npe 's/^(.*)!(.*)!(.*)!(.*)!(.*)!(.*)!(.*)!(.*)!(.*)!(.*)!(.*)$/$1|$2|$3|$4|$5|$6|$7|$8|$9|$10|$11/'
```

Thanks!